# python.multiprocessing и изменение shared-memory object

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Можно ли применить в multiprocessing функцию, которая имеет внутри цикл, в каждой итерации записывающий новую строку в результат?

Буду благодарен если напишите какие инструменты для этого нужны: manager(),Namespace(),lock() и т.д.

Еще больше буду благодарен за ссылку на похожие проблемы, самое близкое, что я нашел - https://www.appsloveworld.com/pandas/100/196/share-dataframe-in-python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
import heapq
import pandas as pd


def my_func(df):
    df_res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['result1', 'result2'])

    def insert_row(df, my_row):
        df.loc[len(df)] = my_row

    # modify df here
    df2 = pd.read_csv  # ...
    df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, on=['field'])
    # getting values here
    for ix in df3.index:
        dct = df2[df2['field'] == df3.loc[ix]['field']].values.tolist()
        result1, result2 = heapq.heappop(dct)
        # here i want to insert row into parent dataframe (df_res2) in the main process
        # but now i use concat method below
        insert_row(df_res, (result1, result2))
    return df_res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], 'c': [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]})
    df_res2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['result1', 'result2'])
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)) as pool:
        groups = (g for _, g in df.groupby("a"))
        print(df)
        print(groups)
        out = []
        for res in pool.imap_unordered(my_func, groups):
            out.append(res)
    final_df = pd.concat(out)
```

EDITED:
Так как мой пример упрощён - напишу саму задачу:
Есть df - Операции, отсортированные по приоритетности. И df2 - ресурсы выполнения задачи (например люди) и их фонды рабочего времени. Для каждой операции в определённый месяц подбирается исполнитель с наибольшим фондом рабочего времени. После этого фонд исполнителя в df2 уменьшается на трудоемкость операции.
В текущей версии все решается в цикле с помощью heapq.heappop() - который подбирает свободного исполнителя. Почему цикл? - присутствуют дополнительные вычисления в каждой итерации - после подбора нужно уменьшить фонд подобранного исполнителя до расчета следующей итерации, а также создаются доп переменные: успеют или нет, возможно нужно подобрать второго исполнителя  и т.д. Альтернативы циклу для такого я не нашел - а мультипроцессинг в этом плане очень помогает - ведь можно независимо рассчитать на каждый месяц и сделать это быстро, так от меня и хотят))

Comment: Вы это с учебными целями или для реальной задачи? Для реальной задачи лучше алгоритм обработки продумать, а не пытаться спасать скорость мультипроцессингом. Неэффективный алгоритм и накладные расходы на процессы всё-равно выигрыша в итоге не дадут.

Comment: Задача реальная - но пример конечно очень упрощённый... хотя heapq.heappop() там правда используется, альтернативы делать это без цикла пока не нашел. А так как строк очень много - мультипроцессинг на самом деле очень спасает)) Даже такой корявый... А можете в 2 словах сказать что под алгоритмом обработки вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Вы лучше напишите в вопросе, какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить вообще. Я пока только вижу, что с `Pandas` вы явно не оптимально работаете. Но что делать пока не могу сказать, поскольку не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос, надеюсь понятно. В моем понимании, если я смогу построчно записывать результат из цикла в df_res2 из каждого процесса - это будет оптимальнее и меня в будущем не будет волновать проблема multiprocessing.pool stuck - она на всякий случай описана здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77324716/stucking-of-python-multiprocessing-pool

Comment: Судя по описанию задачи, вам скорее нужна какая-то `SQL` база и вычисления в коде. `Pandas` для таких задач не самая оптимальная штука. В частности построчная вставка в датафрейм - штука долгая, особенно если датафрейм большой. Либо копите строки в списке/словаре и потом в конце делайте из них датафрейм, это будет гораздо быстрее.